# How to get text from textarea including the newline characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jquery, I am trying to get the text from a textarea tag, with the new lines as `\n` and not `br` tags. The problem is if I select it and get its val, the firefox debugger does not even show the `\n` or `br`. If I alert it, then I see there is two lines, but then if I insert it into the DOM, it removes all the new lines. I want it to keep its new lines.

I get it like this:

```
var handleSend = function(thread_id) {
    var user = GLOBAL_DATA.user;

    $(context).find("#message-form").unbind('submit').submit(function() {

        var field = $(this).find("textarea");

        runAJAXSerial($(this).serialize(), {
            page : 'message/setmessage',
            id : user['id'],
            thread_id : thread_id
        }, function(response) {
            var user = GLOBAL_DATA.user;

            var obj = {
                user_id : user['id'],
                message : field[0].value.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n"),
                date_sent : getDate() + ' ' + getTime()
            };
            alert(obj.message);
            cleanResponse(obj);

            field.val("").focus();

            displayMessages([obj], true);
        }, function(data,status,xhr) {

        });

        return false;
    });
};

function cleanResponse(response) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call( response ) === '[object Array]') {
        var i = 0, l = response.length;
        for (i=0; i<l; i+=1) {
            response[i] = cleanResponse(response[i]);
        }
    } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call( response ) === '[object Object]') {
        for (var property in response) {
            if (response.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                response[property] = cleanResponse(response[property]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        response = escapeHTML(response);
    }
    return response;
}

function escapeHTML(str) {
    return $("<p/>").text(str).html();
}

var displayMessages = function(response, onBottom) {
    var user = GLOBAL_DATA.user, i=0, l=response.length, acc = '';

    for(i=0; i<l; i+=1) {
        var obj = response[i];

        var acc_temp = "";
        acc_temp += '<div class="message ' + (obj['user_id']==user['id'] ? 'message-right' : 'message-left') + '">';
        acc_temp += '<img src="' + getImage(obj['user_id']) + '" align="right" class="message-image" />';
        acc_temp += '<div>' + Autolinker.link(obj['message']) + '</div>';
        acc_temp += '<br/>';
        if (obj['user_id']!=user['id']) {
            acc_temp += '<div class="message-details">' + obj['first_name'] + ' ' + obj['last_name'] + '</div>';
        }
        acc_temp += '<div class="message-details">' + obj['date_sent'] + '</div>';
        acc_temp += '</div>';

        acc = acc_temp + acc;
    }

    addMessage(acc, onBottom);
};

var addMessage = function(html, onBottom) {
    var list = $(context).find("#message-list");
    if (onBottom) {
        list.append(html);
        scrollBot();
    } else {
        list.prepend(html);
    }
};
```

`displayMessages` inserts the text into the DOM.
`cleanResponse` encodes the text so that the user can't execute scripts.

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, for your use case are you expecting/allowing the user to insert HTML into the textarea?

Comment: No, they can, but I encode it so whatever they type shows on the screen and not executed literally. This also removes br tags. So I want new lines `\n` to work.

Comment: It may be easier to write a few JS replace statements to match up things like \n and replace them with <br />, at least that's how I've done it in the past.  \n doesn't really play consistently across different platforms and technologies is another lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New lines in the DOM are treated like any other whitespace. You are getting the expected behaviour of adding the new lines.

If you want an new line to be *rendered* then you need to use a `<br>` element or modify the `white-space` CSS property.

Comment: How do I modify the css property? I want to get newlines to work without br tags.

Comment: Usually by writing a stylesheet with an appropriate selector.

Comment: I mean like what value do I give to the white-space css rule?